# How to select a ListView row and highlight it (several TextViews)?

Tags: android, listview

I have a`ListView`where each row has three TextViews displaying information about an Object called Medidor (Meter).

My question is: How can I mark the whole row as selected when an onClick event happens? I just need to darken the current row color if selected, or return to normal otherwise.

I think about using setOnItemClickListener on the list that holds the Objects (`ArrayList<Medidor> medidores` on my `Activity`, but I don't know exactly how it relates to the `Adapter` and specifically to the `getView` method in order to make it work.

This is the code of my Adapter:

```
public class ListaMedidoresAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Medidor> medidores;
    private Activity activity;
    private TextView codMedidor;
    private TextView nombreMedidor;
    private TextView obsLectMedidor;
    static Long cod_medidor_seleccionado = 0L;
    private static final Boolean COLORES_UBICS_ALTERN = false; //false para agrupar las ubicaciones en colores distintos para cada ubicación

    private static final String[] colores_tabla = {"#770077","#002222","#228822","#881133","#602000","#202020","#6432c8","#c8323e","#32c870","#32a9c8","#c8b632","#c84f32","#383332","#6a7c68","#72687c","#590346","#5652c4","#404c33","#4a13ef","#ef6013",
            "#724c12","#062307","#159fb5","#77797a","#107ea3","#a31010","#663c3c","#a00088","#383637","#662222","#224466","#5c748c","#8c875c","#5c8c80","#70962a","#3722f4","#a36758","#8e5518","#61188e","#af0150",
            "#214add","#697293","#4f5466","#02686d","#2d026d","#7b6899","#50ba5f","#e85e27","#a4ba01","#ff0026"};

    private static final String[] colores_altern = {"#2b7f4a","#7f2b30"};

    private String color_seleccionado_conjunto = "";

    private ArrayList<Integer> colores_seleccionados;
    private Integer color_selecc;

    private Context ctx;

    ListaMedidoresAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Medidor> listaMedidores, Context ctx){
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.medidores = listaMedidores;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        colores_seleccionados = new ArrayList<>();
        color_selecc = 0;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return medidores.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Medidor getItem(int i) {
        return medidores.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fila_medidor,null);
            codMedidor = convertView.findViewById(R.id.codigo_medidor);
            nombreMedidor = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_medidor);
            obsLectMedidor = convertView.findViewById(R.id.estado_lects_medidor);
        }
        Medidor m = medidores.get(position);

        nombreMedidor.setText(m.getNombre());
        obsLectMedidor.setText(m.getLecturaStatus());
        obsLectMedidor.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

        if(m.getCodigo_medidor() == null){ //Es cabecera de ubicación
            nombreMedidor.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            if(COLORES_UBICS_ALTERN){ //Seleccionar alternadamente entre dos colores
                codMedidor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colores_altern[color_selecc]));
                nombreMedidor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colores_altern[color_selecc]));
                obsLectMedidor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colores_altern[color_selecc]));
                color_selecc = (color_selecc == 0) ? 1:0;
            } else { //Seleccionar un color al azar
                color_seleccionado_conjunto = seleccionarColor();
                codMedidor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color_seleccionado_conjunto));
                nombreMedidor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color_seleccionado_conjunto));
                obsLectMedidor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color_seleccionado_conjunto));
            }
        } else { //Es un medidor
            if(COLORES_UBICS_ALTERN){ //Seleccionar alternadamente entre dos colores
                codMedidor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colores_altern[color_selecc]));
                nombreMedidor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colores_altern[color_selecc]));
                color_selecc = (color_selecc == 0) ? 1:0;
            } else { //Seleccionar un color al azar
                codMedidor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color_seleccionado_conjunto));
                nombreMedidor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color_seleccionado_conjunto));
            }
            if(m.getCodigo_medidor() != null){
                String codMedidorAbreviado = m.getCodigo_medidor().split(" ")[1] + m.getCodigo_medidor().split(" ")[2];
                codMedidor.setText(codMedidorAbreviado);
            }
            switch (m.getLecturaStatus()){
                case "S/L":
                    obsLectMedidor.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case "OBS":
                    obsLectMedidor.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    break;
                case "OK":
                    obsLectMedidor.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                default:
                    obsLectMedidor.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    break;
            }
        }
        TextView ubicacionMedidor = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ubicacionMedidorSelecc);
        return convertView;
    }

    private String seleccionarColor(){
        Integer ran_num=0;
        Random ran = new Random();
        Boolean new_ran = false;
        while(new_ran == false){
            ran_num = ran.nextInt(50);
            Log.i("RAN",ran_num.toString());
            Boolean yaSeleccionado = false;
            if(colores_seleccionados.size() < 50) {
                for (int i = 0; i < colores_seleccionados.size(); i++) {
                    if (colores_seleccionados.get(i) == ran_num) {
                        Log.i("COLORS", "Color seleccionado ya existe en posición " + ran_num.toString());
                        yaSeleccionado = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                new_ran = !yaSeleccionado;
            } else { //Ya fueron todos los colores disponibles seleccionados, ahora sólo debe asegurarse que no elija el mismo color que la ubicación anterior
                if(ran_num != colores_seleccionados.get(colores_seleccionados.size()-1)){
                    new_ran = true;
                }
            }
        }
        colores_seleccionados.add(ran_num);
        Log.i("RAN_COLOR",colores_tabla[ran_num]);
        return colores_tabla[ran_num];
    }
}
```

The color related stuff chooses background color for the "rows" (via the TextView objects) in order to visually separate Medidor objects which have a different attribute value (location).

This is fila_medidor.xml (where the three TextView objects are defined in a "row"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/codigo_medidor"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nombre_medidor"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/estado_lects_medidor"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my Activity I have the following lines related to the ListView - Adapter:

```
ListaMedidoresAdapter adapter = new ListaMedidoresAdapter(this,arregloMedidores,this);
listaMedidores.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where `arregloMedidores` is of type `ArrayList<Medidor>`.

Why didn't I choose a `TableLayout`? Because in my opinion it is harder to attach to a dynamic data source like an Array, and also it consumes more resources because it holds all Views in memory, which could be an issue for 1000 entries.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look of my comment and answer to question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493713/wrong-scrolling-with-highliting-in-listview-when-searching-item/47586041#47586041 Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try add line:
android:background="@drawable/medidor_background" 
to your fila_medidor.xml LinearLayout

then create a new medidor_background.xml file in drawable folder with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#000000"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#FFFFFF"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```